# Difference between "*" and "Any" in Kotlin generics

Tags: generics, kotlin

I am not sure I fully understand the difference between `SomeGeneric<*>` and `SomeGeneric<Any>`.  I think `*` represents anything (wild card) and `Any` represents the object which **ALL** objects inherit from.  So it seems they should be the same, but are they?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

It may be helpful to think of the [star projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) as a way to represent not just any type, but some fixed type which you don't know what is exactly.

For example, the type `MutableList<*>` represents the list of *something* (you don't know what exactly). So if you try to add something to this list, you won't succeed. It may be a list of `String`s, or a list of `Int`s, or a list of something else. The compiler won't allow to put any object in this list at all because it cannot verify that the list accepts objects of this type. However, if you attempt to get an element out of such list, you'll surely get an object of type `Any?`, because all objects in Kotlin inherit from `Any`.

*From [asco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804967/asco) comment below:*

> Additionally `List<*>` can contain objects of any type, but only that
>   type, so it can contain Strings (but only Strings), while `List<Any>`
>   can contain Strings and Integers and whatnot, all in the same list.

Comment: Here an interesting article with a similar explanation: https://typealias.com/guides/star-projections-and-how-they-work/

Comment: @fweigl I don't think it's correct to make the distinction this way. `List<*>` can very much contain mixed types as well. Here: `val list: List<*> = listOf(42, "Bob")`. You just don't know what `*` is, and `*` may very well be any parent type you like, including `Any` itself (like in my example). The only important difference is that for contravariant or invariant types like `MutableList<T>`, the "`in` operations" are forbidden when using `*` because you don't statically know what the type parameter is, so the compiler can't make any assumption.

Answer (score 145):

The key to understanding the star projection(`*`) is to properly understand the other two type projections `in` and `out` first. After that, the star projection becomes self-explanatory.

---

### Understanding the problem

Let's say that you have this generic class `Crate` that you intend to use for storing fruits. This class is invariant in `T`. This means, this class can consume as well as produce `T` (fruits). In other words, this class has functions that take `T` as argument(consume) as well as return `T`(produce). The `size()` function is T-independent, it neither takes `T` nor does it return `T`:

```
class Crate<T> {
    private val items = mutableListOf<T>()
    fun produce(): T = items.last()
    fun consume(item: T) = items.add(item)
    fun size(): Int = items.size
}
```

But what if you want to use this already existing class just as a producer(`out T`) or just as a consumer(`in T`) or not want to use `T` but just its T-independent functions like `size()`? Without worrying about the accidental use of the unwanted functionality?

The solution is, we project the types by using variance modifiers `out`, `in` and `*` at the use-site. *Use-site* simply means wherever we use the `Crate` class.

---

### `out` projection is a producer of `T`

By projecting the `Crate` as `out`, you are telling the compiler: "give me an error when I accidentally use the `Crate` class as a consumer of `T` because I just want to safely use that class as a producer `T`":

```
fun useAsProducer(producer: Crate<out Fruit>) {

    // T is known to be out Fruit, so produces Fruit and its subtypes.
    val fruit = producer.produce()           // OK

    // Fruit is guaranteed. Can use functions and properties of Fruit.
    fruit.getColor()                         // OK
    
    // Consumer not allowed because you don't want to accidentally add
    // oranges, if this is a Crate<Apple>
    producer.consume(Orange())               // Error             
}
```

---

### `in` projection is a consumer of `T`

By projecting the `Crate` as `in`, you are telling the compiler: "give me an error when I accidentally use the `Crate` class as a producer of `T` because I just want to safely use that class as a consumer of `T`":

```
fun useAsConsumer(consumer: Crate<in Orange>) {

    // Produces Any?, no guarantee of Orange because this could
    // be a Crate<Fruit> with apples in it.
    val anyNullable = consumer.produce()     // Not useful
    
    // Not safe to call functions of Orange on the produced items.
    anyNullable.getVitaminC()                // Error

    // T is known to be in Orange, so consumes Orange and its subtypes.
    consumer.consume(MandarinOrange())       // OK
}
```

---

### Star projection is no producer, no consumer of `T`

By projecting the `Crate` as `*`, you are telling the compiler: "give me an error when I accidentally use the `Crate` class as a producer or consumer of `T` because I don't want to use the functions or properties that consume and produce `T`. I just want to safely use the T-independent functions and properties like `size()`":

```
fun useAsStar(star: Crate<*>) {

    // T is unknown, so the star produces the default supertype Any?.
    val anyNullable = star.produce()         // Not useful

    // T is unknown, cannot access its properties and functions.
    anyNullable.getColor()                   // Error

    // Cannot consume because you don't know the type of Crate.
    star.consume(Fruit())                    // Error

    // Only use the T-independent functions and properties.
    star.size()                              // OK
}
```

---

### `Any` is not a projection

When you say `Crate<Any>`, you are not projecting, you are simply using the original invariant class `Crate<T>` as it is, which can *produce* as well as *consume* `Any`:

```
fun useAsAny(any: Crate<Any>) {

    // T is known to be Any. So, an invariant produces Any.
    val anyNonNull = any.produce()           // OK

    // T is known to be Any. So, an invariant consumes Any.
    any.consume(Fruit())                     // OK

    // Can use the T-independent functions and properties, of course.
    any.size()                               // OK
}
```

The same is true for `Crate<Apple>` or any other similar type without a variance modifier `in`, `out`, or `*`, it will consume and produce that type (`Apple` in that case). It's not a projection. This explains the difference between `SomeGeneric<*>` and `SomeGeneric<Any>`, you can compare the two code snippets above, side by side.

---

### Star projection for declaration-site producer

So far, we saw the type projections `out`, `in` and `*` for the `Crate` class that was invariant at declaration-site: `Crate<T>`. From here on, let's find out how the star projection behaves with the classes that are already `in` and `out` at the declaration-site with type parameter bounds:

**Declaration-site**

```
class ProducerCrate<out T : Fruit> {
    private val fruits = listOf<T>()
    fun produce() : T = fruits.last()
}
```

**Use-site**

```
fun useProducer(star: ProducerCrate<*>) {

    // Even though we project * here, it is known to be at least a Fruit
    // because it's an upper bound at the declaration-site.
    val fruit = star.produce()               // OK

    // Fruit is guaranteed. Can use functions and properties of Fruit.
    fruit.getColor()                         // OK
}
```

---

### Star projection for declaration-site consumer

**Declaration-site**

```
class ConsumerCrate<in T> {
    private val items = mutableListOf<T>()
    fun consume(item: T) = items.add(item)
    fun size(): Int = items.size
}
```

**Use-site**

```
fun useConsumer(consumer: ConsumerCrate<*>) {

    // Cannot consume anything, because the lower bound is not supported
    // in Kotlin and T is unknown
    consumer.consume(Orange())               // Error

    // Only useful for T-independent functions and properties.
    consumer.size()                          // OK
}
```

Note that the lower bound is not supported in Kotlin. So, in the `ConsumerCrate` class above, we cannot have something like `in T super Orange`(lower bound) like we have `out T : Orange`(upper bound).

---

### Star projection for declaration-site invariant

**Declaration-site**

```
class ProducerConsumerCrate<T : Fruit> {
    private val fruits = mutableListOf<T>()
    fun produce(): T = fruits.last()
    fun consume(fruit: T) = fruits.add(fruit)
}
```

**Use-site**

```
fun useProducerConsumer(producerConsumer: ProducerConsumerCrate<*>) {

    // Even though we project * here, T is known to be at least a Fruit
    // because it's the upper bound at the declaration-site.
    val fruit = producerConsumer.produce()   // OK

    // Fruit is guaranteed. Can use functions and properties of Fruit.
    fruit.getColor()                         // OK

    // Consumer not allowed because you don't want to accidentally add
    // oranges, if this crate is a Crate<Apple>.
    producerConsumer.consume(Fruit())        // Error
}
```

---

### Conclusion

Type projections for the invariant `Crate<T>`:

| Projections | Produces | Consumes | Behaviour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `Crate<Fruit>` | `Fruit` | `Fruit` | Producer and Consumer |
| `Crate<out Fruit>` | `Fruit` | `Nothing` | Producer only |
| `Crate<in Fruit>` | `Any?` | `Fruit` | Consumer only |
| `Crate<*>` | `Any?` | `Nothing` | No Producer and No Consumer |

Comment: Incredible answer! Thanks for your writeup!

Comment: Incredible answer! you answer the question in a very detail and meaningful way. It is very useful for kotlin newbie to understand the invariant.

Comment: That's what an explanation should look like! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wow someone should request that this be added to the official kotlin docs... way better than their explanations

Answer (score 35):

In the context I think you imply, `SomeGeneric<*>` is equivalent to `SomeGeneric<out Any?>`. The Java equivalent is `SomeGeneric<? extends Object>`.

The syntax called "star-projections". Here are the official docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections

Answer (score 0):

to add some simplicity to others answers, the first thing you need to know is that `Any` is **bigger** and it is **The root of the Kotlin class hierarchy. Every Kotlin class has Any as a superclass** by kotlin own definitions.
So they created the `star projection` so you could have any type to a list or whatever that you don't know the type yet. you can  checkout `package kotlin.reflect` in-order to take a closer look.
If Kotlin didn't ever came up with this we could use out-projection like `<out Any?>` or in-projection like `<in Nothing>`
for a deeper dive you should check out this :

[star-Projections and How They Work](https://typealias.com/guides/star-projections-and-how-they-work/)