# Difference between Any type and Generics in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have the following function definition.

```
fun<T> parse(a: Any): T = when (a) {
    is String -> a
    else -> false
}
```

I guessed it should be valid. However, the IntelliJ IDEA linter shows a type mismatch error

[image: Linter error]

That being said, I would change the return type of my parse function to Any, right? So that, what is the difference between using Any type and Generics in Kotlin? In which cases should use each of those?

I did read the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138923/difference-between-and-any-in-kotlin-generics) but not understood at all about star-projection in Kotlin due to the fact I am quite new.

Comment: This Java answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207115/java-generics-t-vs-object

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return type it defined as `T`, but there is nothing assuring that `T` and `a:Any` are related. `T` may be more restrictive than `Any`, in which case you can't return a boolean or whatever you provided for `a`.

The following will work, by changing the return type from `T` to `Any`:

```
fun<T> parse(a: Any): Any = when (a) {
    is String -> a
    else -> false
}
```

Any alternate option, if you really want to return type T:

```
inline fun<reified T> parse(a: Any): T? = when (a) {
    is T -> a
    else -> null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example does not use `T` and thus it's nonsense to make it generic anyways.

Think about this: As a client you put something into a function, e.g. an XML-`ByteArray` which the function is supposed to parse into an `Object`. Calling the function you do not want to have it return `Any` (Casting sucks) but want the function return the type of the parsed object. THIS can be achieved with generics:

```
fun <T> parse(xml: ByteArray): T {
     val ctx: JAXBContext = JAXBContext.newInstance()
     val any = ctx.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(ByteArrayInputStream(xml))
     return any as T
}

val int = parse<Int>("123".toByteArray())
val string = parse<String>("123".toByteArray())
```

Look at the method calls: You tell with generics what type is expected to be returned. The code is not useful and only supposed to give you an idea of generics.

Answer (score 1):

> I guessed it should be valid

Why would it be? You return a `String` in one branch and a `Boolean` in the other. So the common type for the entire `when` expression is `Any` and that's what the compiler (and IDEA) says is "found". Your code also says it should be `T` (which is "required").

Your generic method should work for any `T`, e.g. for `Int`, but `Any` isn't a subtype of `Int` and so the code isn't valid.

> So that, what is the difference between using Any type and Generics in Kotlin?

This is like asking "what is the difference between using numbers and files": they don't have much in common in the first place. You use generics to write code which can work with all types `T` (or with all types satisfying some constraint); you use `Any` when you want the specific type `Any`.

Comment: Is there a good illustration of using `Any` together with `T`?  Or are generics completely optional in Kotlin