# How to read star projection into variable with correct type for particular example?

Tags: kotlin

```
var userAttributes = mapOf<Any?, Any?>()

val responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(userInfoEndpointUri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map::class.java)

userAttributes = responseEntity.body // compilation error
```

results in compilation error:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch:
required Map<Any?, Any?>
found    Map<*,*>!
```

I find myself clueless what **userAttributes** must be declared with to hold such return type.

When I looked at other answers they explain theory, but provide no solution. I understand that the type **Any** for userAttributes is incorrect I don't know what is correct type(well I know it is **out of Any?** which can't be used for the same reason I can't use * to be put as generic type for userAttributes , both resulting in "Projections are not allowed on type arguments of functions and properties")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "\*" and "Any" in Kotlin generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138923/difference-between-and-any-in-kotlin-generics)

Comment: @jrtapsell can you please read the addition at the bottom in my question? Where do you see the solution in the answer you have referenced? 
I cannot use var userAttributes = mapOf<*, *>()

Theory is not helpful without examples.

Answer (score 0):

As some readers of the question mark it as duplicate and point it to theoretical answer to get their blind points I will do reverse, the answer to my problem was to change declaration to:

```
var userAttributes : Map<out Any?, Any?>
```

If someone who understands it better takes my answer and adds explanation of how and why it works and why :

```
var userAttributes = mapOf<Any?, Any?>()
```

does not - i.e. why I could not use **out** for `mapOf` or use projection *, I will gladly accept it as an answer.