# Specify difference between <*>, <T> and <Any> in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have so much confusion among `<T>, <*>` and `<Any>` casting of any object. Can any one have proper explanation with example for this?

Comment: Have u read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138923/difference-between-and-any-in-kotlin-generics

Comment: Read this [kotlin Type projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections)

Comment: yes but i can not able to understand that answer.