# Kotlin: Adding generics to a List<Any>

Tags: kotlin, generics, types

I have a generic object:

```
data class MyObject<T>(
    val entity: T
)
```

I want to concatenate two lists of these objects, with different types T, and return them.

I tried

```
fun concatLists(): List<MyObject<Any>> {
val listOfAs = listOf(MyObject<A>())
val listOfBs = listOf(MyObject<B>())

return mutableListOf<MyObject<Any>>().also {
            it.addAll(listOfAs)
            it.addAll(listOfBs)
        }
}
```

however I get the error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Collection<MyObject<Any>>
Found:
List<MyObject<A>>
```

I don't understand why this error is being thrown as I thought Collection was a child of List, and type A was a child of Any, that this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use case you can use [star projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#star-projections), like

```
fun concatLists(): List<MyObject<*>> {
    val listOfAs = listOf(MyObject(A()))
    val listOfBs = listOf(MyObject(B()))

    return mutableListOf<MyObject<*>>().also {
        it.addAll(listOfAs)
        it.addAll(listOfBs)
    }
}
```

See also [Difference between "*" and "Any" in Kotlin generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138923/difference-between-and-any-in-kotlin-generics)

Comment: I would add that a simple `listOfAs + listOfBs` would do

Answer (score 2):

The way you've defined `MyObject` means that `MyObject<Any>` is not a "supertype" of `MyObject<A>` nor `MyObject<B>`. You'd run into this problem even without collections being involved. The following:

```kotlin
val aObj: MyObject<A> = MyObject(A())
val anyObj: MyObject<Any> = aObj
```

Would also fail to compile.

Let's consider an example closer to the code in your question:

```kotlin
class Foo<T>(var bar: T)

fun main() {
    val intFoos = listOf<Foo<Int>>(Foo(42))
    val longFoos = listOf<Foo<Long>>(Foo(117))
    
    val anyFoos = mutableListOf<Foo<Any>>().also {
        it.addAll(intFoos)
        it.addAll(longFoos)
    }
    anyFoos[0].bar = "a string"
}
```

The above won't compile, but now you should be able to see **why**. This code would allow you to assign any type of object, such as `String`, to the `Foo.bar` property, despite all of the `Foo`s being parameterized with either `Int` or `Long`.

That said, you real class looks like this:

```kotlin
data class MyObject<T>(val entity: T)
```

That class is functioning solely as a *producer* of `T`. In other words, there are no `var` properties with the type `T` nor any functions with a parameter of type `T` (nothing *consumes* `T`). You can use [declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) to specify this fact.

```kotlin
data class MyObject<out T>(val entity: T)
```

And now what you're trying to do will work. You can see this with the above example after changing it to:

```kotlin
class Foo<out T>(val bar: T)

fun main() {
    val intFoos = listOf<Foo<Int>>(Foo(42))
    val longFoos = listOf<Foo<Long>>(Foo(117))
    
    val anyFoos = mutableListOf<Foo<Any>>().also {
        it.addAll(intFoos)
        it.addAll(longFoos)
    }
}
```

It now compiles, though note that `bar` had to be changed from a `var` property to a `val` property.

If declaration-site variance is not a viable option for you then there are two other possible solutions:

1. [Use-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections); build a list of `MyObject<out Any>`.
2. [Star-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#star-projections); build a list of `MyObject<*>` (see [Ivo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77599908/6395627) for an example of this).

Comment: Excellent answer. Me myself also still often get confused about `in` and `out` and I actually haven't run into a situation where I had to use it. I think many software developers rarely have to deal with it, which is also why many aren't that familiar with it. It didn't cross my mind that indicating `out` would also solve it but it makes perfect sense once you realize how it works